# App crashes(?) on closing?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, ios-simulator, xcode4.5

I am new to iPhone development, so I don't really know if this is a stupid question or not...  I run my app in the simulator and everything works great.  I then press the home button in the simulator.  I then double press home and close my app from the multitasking bar.  The xcode window then pops up and in green text it says `lldb`.  On a side note, the app won't run on the ios simulator unless I run it from xcode..  Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's nothing to worry about, dude.

`1)It happens only whenever you delete the running instance (app) of the app from the Home panel of the simulator/device.`

`2)It will also happen if you unplug your`iphone device`from the`Mac`during the debug Mode application.`

So don't worry about that, it's not a bug!

Comment: I don't have a developer account yet, but this wont happen if I put in on my iphone when I get an account?

Answer (score 1):

IOS is correct, its normal. It will also do this if you unplug your iphone from the Mac during a test. :)